# Searching data depending on conditions

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, search, if-statement

I have three textboxes and one dropdown as shown in image below.Now on submit button click i have to check 16 cases by applying if-else blocks.Following is the code i am currently using:

[image]

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime date = System.DateTime.Today;
    string strdate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");

    //Response.Write("class=" + drpclass.SelectedIndex + "tchrname=" + txt_tchrname.Text + "studentcode=" + txt_studentcode.Text + "date=" + strDTentered1);

    if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";

        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        //            lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "' and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");

        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";

        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "' and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }

    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";

        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'";
        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "' and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "'";

        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        // lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'  and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "'";
        goto RC_sql;

    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {
        //  lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "'  and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "' and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'";

        goto RC_sql;
    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        // lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate + "'  and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        goto RC_sql;

    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        // lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'  and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'";
        goto RC_sql;

    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'  and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "' and tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        goto RC_sql;

    }
    else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
    {
        // lbl_norecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        //DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
        string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
        string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
        strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'  and  tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
        goto RC_sql;

    }
    //else if (drpclass.SelectedIndex == 0 && txt_tchrname.Text.Length == 0 && txt_studentcode.Text.Length == 0 && txtdatesearch.Text.Length == 0)
    //{

    //    //DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
    //    ////DateTime  = CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate.Value;
    //    //string strDTentered1 = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
    //    //string studentcode = "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%";
    //    //strwhere = " DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'  and  tblhomework.StudentsCode like'" + studentcode + "' and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'";
    //    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "<script language=JavaScript>alert('Please fill atleast one field ');</script>");

    //}
    else
    //{
    //    lbl_norecord.Text = "Please fill atleast one Field";
    //    lbl_norecord.Visible = true;
    {
        classalert.Visible = true;
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecordtoday.Visible = false;
        grdhomework.Visible = false;
        goto RC_EXIT;

    }

RC_sql:
    sqlsearch = "SELECT tblhomework.ID,tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,tblclass.CLASSNAME,tblhomework.Title,tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,tblhomework.StudentsCode FROM tblhomework" +
        " join tblclass on tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode join tblteacher on tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode where " + strwhere;
    ds = obj.openDataset(sqlsearch, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());

    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
    {
        //lbl_norecord.Text = "Record Not Found";
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = true; grdhomework.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = true;
        classnorecordtoday.Visible = false;
        classalert.Visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        grdhomework.Visible = true;
        grdhomework.DataSource = ds;
        grdhomework.DataBind();
        blankdata();
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecordtoday.Visible = false;
        classalert.Visible = false;
    }
RC_EXIT:
    Response.Write("");
}
```

Now i want some way where i dont have to make so many if else conditions.Because if-else conditions increases as no of textboxes increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write in following fashion:

```
String drpClassString = ""

If(drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
  drpString = " and tblhomework.ClassCode='" + drpclass.SelectedItem.Value + "'"
}
String thrNameString = "";
if(txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0)
{
thrNameString = " and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'"
}
String dateString = ""
if( txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0)
{
dateString =" and DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strDTentered1 + "'"
}


String sqlsearch = "SELECT tblhomework.ID,tblteacher.TEACHERNAME,tblclass.CLASSNAME,tblhomework.Title,tblhomework.HomeworkDetail,tblhomework.StudentsCode FROM tblhomework" +
        " join tblclass on tblclass.CLASSCODE=tblhomework.ClassCode join tblteacher on tblteacher.TSHORTNAME=tblhomework.Tshortcode where 1 = 1" + drpClassString + thrNameString +dateString;
```

hope this helps.

Comment: thanx till now it solved my purpose...will ask you if will face any problem further so please keep on checking this question today and tomorrow or give me your email id..thanx again

Answer (score 0):

Using `StringBuilder` Create a `string` for Search.

**BETTER ONE IS USE STRING BUILDER**

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
DateTime date = System.DateTime.Today;
String strdate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
sb.append(" DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y')='" + strdate);

if(drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
//sb.append("ClassName='"+ drpclass.SelectedValue.Text + "'")
}
if(string.isEmptyorNull(txtTecher.Text))
{
//sb.append("TeacherName='" +txtTecher.Text+"'")
}
//write other condition 
//Sql Query="select * from  where"+sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to accomplish this (in practice) is to re-write your query so that:

1. it is not dependant on the values.
2. if the values are present, they are parameterized to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (using `System.Data.Odbc` because you're using MySQL).

Below is one way to write your query:

```
SELECT  tblhomework.ID
        , tblteacher.TEACHERNAME
        , tblclass.CLASSNAME
        , tblhomework.Title
        , tblhomework.HomeworkDetail
        , tblhomework.StudentsCode
FROM    tblhomework
        JOIN tblclass
            ON  tblclass.CLASSCODE = tblhomework.ClassCode
        JOIN tblteacher
            ON  tblteacher.TSHORTNAME = tblhomework.Tshortcode
WHERE   (tblhomework.ClassCode = @dropClass OR @dropClass IS NULL)           -- effectively ignores this portion of WHERE clause if @dropClass IS NULL
        AND (tblhomework.TshortCode = @teacherName OR @teacherName IS NULL)  -- effectively ignores this portion of WHERE clause if @teacherName IS NULL
        AND (tblhomework.StudentsCode LIKE @studentCode)                     -- ternary operator in code-behind sets to wildcarded actual value or just a wildcard
        AND (DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y') = @dateEntered) -- if condition in code-behind sets to current date or custom date
```

Then in your code-behind, you can write your `if` conditions (once) to set each individiual parameter:

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // define relevant date
    string strDate = string.Empty;
    if (txtdatesearch.Text.Length != 0) { // one "if condition" to determine which date to use
        DateTime DTentered1 = DateTime.ParseExact(txtdatesearch.Text, CalendarExtender1.Format, null);
        strDate = DTentered1.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
    } else {
        strDate = System.DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yy");
    }
    // define query
    string query = "SELECT tblhomework.ID, tblteacher.TEACHERNAME, tblclass.CLASSNAME, tblhomework.Title, tblhomework.HomeworkDetail, tblhomework.StudentsCode FROM tblhomework JOIN tblclass ON tblclass.CLASSCODE = tblhomework.ClassCode JOIN tblteacher ON tblteacher.TSHORTNAME = tblhomework.Tshortcode WHERE (tblhomework.ClassCode = @dropClass OR @dropClass IS NULL) AND (tblhomework.TshortCode = @teacherName OR @teacherName IS NULL) AND (tblhomework.StudentsCode LIKE @studentCode) AND (DATE_FORMAT(tblhomework.DateCreated,'%d-%m-%y') = @dateEntered)";
    // define connection string
    OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(YourConnectionStringGoesHere);
    OdbcCommand cmd = null;
    // define command
    using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn)) {
        // add parameters using the ternary operator (?:) to handle cases that are not the date.
        // The ternary operator works like an inline "if (condition) {this} else {that}"
        // It's written in the form of "condition ? this : that;"
        cmd.Parameters.Add("dropClass", OdbcType.Int).Value = (drpclass.SelectedIndex != 0 ? drpclass.SelectedItem.Value : System.DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("teacherName", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = (txt_tchrname.Text.Length != 0 ? txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() : System.DBNull.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("studentCode", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = (txt_studentcode.Text.Length != 0 ? "%" + txt_studentcode.Text.ToString() + "%" : "%");
        cmd.Parameters.Add("dateEntered", OdbcType.VarChar, 50).Value = strDate;

        conn.Open();
        // you're using a dataset, and the OdbcCommand returns a reader
        // see the function defined below for ConvertDataReaderToDataSet
        DataSet(ds == ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(cmd.ExecuteReader()));
        // I'm not familiar with the openDataset(String, String) function, and I'm not sure what "obj" is...
        // Is this supposed to cache the result in session?
        // ds = obj.openDataset(sqlsearch, Session["SCHOOLCODE"].ToString());
    }

    if ((ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count == 0)) {
        //lbl_norecord.Text = "Record Not Found";
        //lbl_norecord.Visible = True
        grdhomework.Visible = false;
        classnorecord.Visible = true;
        classnorecordtoday.Visible = false;
        classalert.Visible = false;
        Response.Write("");
    } else {
        grdhomework.Visible = true;
        grdhomework.DataSource = ds;
        grdhomework.DataBind();
        blankdata();
        classnorecord.Visible = false;
        classnorecordtoday.Visible = false;
        classalert.Visible = false;
    }
}
// function ConvertDataReaderToDataSet by Mohammed Fauzi, found at http://mohammedfauzi.blogspot.com/2009/12/convert-datareader-to-dataset-through-c.html
public DataSet ConvertDataReaderToDataSet(System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader reader)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    do {
        // Create data table in runtime
        DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        if (schemaTable != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++) {
                DataRow dataRow = schemaTable.Rows[i];
                // Create a column name as provided in Schema
                string columnName = (string)dataRow["ColumnName"];
                // Define Column Type here
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn(columnName, (Type)dataRow["DataType"]);
                //Adding Column to table
                dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
            }
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
            // Fill the data table from reader data
            while (reader.Read()) {
                DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                    dataRow[i] = reader.GetValue(i);
                }
                dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        } else {
            // No records were returned
            DataColumn column = new DataColumn("RowsAffected");
            dataTable.Columns.Add(column);
            dataSet.Tables.Add(dataTable);
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow[0] = reader.RecordsAffected;
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    } while (reader.NextResult());
    return dataSet;
}
```

I apologize for the delay on this answer. By the time I had it ready, you had already accepted another answer. However I cannot, in good conscience, let this post go without at least mentioning the dangers of [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) inherent in your original post and not addressed in the accepted answer.

Consider for a moment what would happen if your user enters `'; DROP TABLE tblhomework;` for `txt_tchrname.Text`.

```
thrNameString = " and tblhomework.TshortCode='" + txt_tchrname.Text.ToString() + "'"
```

Because you're not using parameterized values, your query now becomes:

```
SELECT  tblhomework.ID
        , tblteacher.TEACHERNAME
        , tblclass.CLASSNAME
        , tblhomework.Title
        , tblhomework.HomeworkDetail
        , tblhomework.StudentsCode
FROM    tblhomework
        JOIN tblclass
            ON  tblclass.CLASSCODE = tblhomework.ClassCode
        JOIN tblteacher
            ON  tblteacher.TSHORTNAME = tblhomework.Tshortcode
WHERE   1 = 1
        AND tblhomework.TshortCode = ''; DROP TABLE tblhomework';
```

and promptly drops your primary table.

When you use parameterized variables, they are evaluated as a type instead of a potential SQL fragment so no executable SQL gets injected into your statement.

Heed the lesson of [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Please.

Your users will thank you.